# scala/spark mapping [String,List[String]] to String pairs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD with structures of `RDD:[String A,List(Strings Bs)]` I would like to map it so that I get an `RDD:[String A,String B]`, so that each element in the List will be matched with String A. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I am currently using `flatMapValues`, would this be the most efficient way? (I have huge dataset)

Comment: Looks like you are using Java API. Please specify what API are you using.

Comment: And yes... flatMapValues is one of the best ways for such a thing.

Comment: Apart from flatMapValues, did you get that RDD from a co-group for instance? If so, using a join instead will produce what you want without this intermediate RDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rdd.flatMapValues(identity)` should get the job done.

That should be a pretty efficient and simple way.
To optimize performance, you could compare it to an implementation using   `mapPartitions` and pick the better of the two. I wouldn't expect a huge difference as in both cases wrapper objects need to be created anyway.

```
rdd.mapPartitions(iter => iter.flatMap(elem => elem._2.map(v => (elem._1,v)))
```